# JSON into PHP: access array data if each array has a different name

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to access data from a JSON file, using PHP.
Here is what the JSON feed looks like:

```
[{
    "performancesByDateDisplay":{
        "2021-09-02":[{
            "performanceId":10813388,
            "performanceTime":"8:00 PM"
        }],
        "2021-09-03":[{
            "performanceId":10813638,
            "performanceTime":"8:00 PM"
        }]
    }
}]
```

And here is the code I am using to access the data:

```
    foreach($json_output->performancesByDateDisplay as $events) {
        $perfId = $events->performanceId;
    }
```

But $perfId is not returning any value. I think it's because each array has a different "name" (for example "2021-09-02" in the first instance)? How do I access the data, without knowing in advance what this name will be (it's coming from an external json feed)?
Thanks!

Comment: but wtf this JSON is so badly encoded !!

Comment: _“I think it's because each array has a different "name" (for example "2021-09-02" in the first instance)”_ - you are thinking wrong; because that’s the “magic” of a `foreach` loop, that you _don’t_ need to know the keys in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Did you forget to decode?

Well, first you need to decode the JSON data into a native PHP structure.

```
$decodedJson = json_decode($json_output, true);
```

Then you can access it just how you'll access a native PHP array and associative array. Notice the `true`, that's to decode the `JSON` string into an associative array. Also, it'd be better to just get inside the array while decoding, hence making the above statement:

```
$decodedJson = json_decode($json_output, true)[0];
```

Now you can iterate over it.

```
foreach($decodedJson as $events) {
    foreach($events as $date => $event) {
        $perfId = $event[0]['performanceId'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the root of your JSON and each "`$events`" item is an array of objects, not just an object.

If you were to iterate each of these arrays for example, and access the objects inside one-by-one, you'd get the expected result:

```
foreach($json_output as $json_output_item){
    foreach($json_output_item->performancesByDateDisplay as $events){
        foreach($events as $event){
            $perfId = $event->performanceId;
            var_dump($perfId);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
int(10813388)
int(10813638)
```

Comment: No, I am still getting a blank page when I try var_dumping it..

Comment: Dude, how can you iterate over a JSON string without decoding it?

Comment: @KashanAhmad Given the attempt provided in the question, I (perhaps wrongly) assumed that `$json_output` was an already-decoded representation of the OP's data.

Comment: @KashanAhmad yes, i didn't include it in my sample code, but the JSON string was already decoded, hence the `$jason_output` variable...